# Get Checkbox label text Selenium C#

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath, checkbox

I'm trying to get the text value of checkbox label. Here is an HTML code

```
<div id="content" class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="example">
  <h3>Checkboxes</h3>
  <form id='checkboxes'>
    <input type="checkbox"> checkbox 1</br>
    <input type="checkbox" checked> checkbox 2
  </form>
</div>
```

So What I have tried so far

1. `Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='checkbox']")).Text`;
2. `Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='checkbox']")).GetAttribute("value");`
3. `Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='checkbox']")).GetAttribute("name");`
4. `Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='checkbox']")).GetAttribute("innerText");`
5. `Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='checkbox']")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");`

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnXhW.png)

All this attempts return `""`.
Any ideas how to get it or Javascript is my only option ?

Comment: there are two check boxes, which one you want?

Comment: Either one of them, but `findelement` should return first element from all elements. And see them but property `Text` has value ` "" ` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath for a text following an input tag is `//input[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]` but there are serious limitations for Selenium to run expressions like this. It only can handle tag elements. Try to get the parent and retrieve texts from there.

```
string[] texts = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@id='checkboxes']"))
   .GetAttribute("innerText")
   .Split("\r\n".ToCharArray()
);
```

Then texts[0] returns:

> checkbox 1

Comment: Thanks a lot it. Really worked.  I got it that the checkbox label a hard coded into a form. I believe this is not the smartest idea to design your page this way but at least I know a solution right now  [Screenshot of what have driver returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyzDX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add an class or id attribute to the checkboxes and then try to find the element by css selector like: Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(""))

Comment: The issue is not that I can't find it or it is not visible, but that I can't return a text value of it.

[link](https://prnt.sc/khv5js)

Answer (score 0):

You can try following to get the required text from the two checkboxes:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@id='checkboxes']/input[@type='checkbox'][1]")).Text
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@id='checkboxes']/input[@type='checkbox'][2]")).Text
```

Let me know, if above code does not work for you.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this option. 

[You can see uploaded screenshot](https://prnt.sc/khv5js)

Comment: Could you retry with `//form[@id='checkboxes']/input[@type='checkbox'][1]` as the xpath for checkbox, as currently I am not sure whether the checkbox `//input[@type='checkbox'][1]` is one the children of `//form[@id='checkboxes']` or some other one.

Comment: [See a result in a screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/u1WVYP8)

Didn't work. The final answer is posted by @derloopkat . I think this is valuable informatio

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CSS Selector to get the checkbox label:

```
Element CheckBox = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='checkbox']"));

string firstChkBoxTxt = CheckBox.FirstOrDefault().GetAttribute("innerText");
string secondChkBoxTxt = CheckBox.LastOrDefault().GetAttribute("innerText");
```